# awk compare two files and print first field in file 1

Tags: awk, diff

I have two files like this.

file 1

```
1:apple
2:banana
3:pineapple
4:guava
5:orange
```

and file 2 like this

```
apple
guava
orange
```

i just want to compare file 2 with file 1 and print the 1st field for the lines missing in file 2.

Required output

```
3
4
```

Code I tried,

> file1 <(cut -d: -f2 file2)

but got the output as below

```
1a2,3
> banana
> pineapple
```

Comment: please provide the full code of your  `diff` and check your required output... it should be `2` and ` 3` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an associative array lookup using Awk?

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} !($2 in a) {print $1}' file2 file1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks, it serves my purpose, awk is a line by line processing wont it take too much time for large size files.

Comment: @upkar Define "large". Note that this solution reads one of the files into memory. If your files are several gigabytes in size, you may have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -vwf file2 file1 | cut -d: -f1
2
3
```